# Getting email of user on social login in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework, facebook-login, hybrid-mobile-app

I m developing a hybrid application for iOS and android using ionic framework over AngularJS and html5. The app has a social login (Facebook and Google) and we need to retrieve the emailId of the logged in user. From Google we are getting the mailId but from Facebook, emailId is not returning anything. I know we have to set the permissions for that.

What I have tried is:

```
.controller('LoginController',['$scope','FIREBASE_REF','$firebaseSimpleLogin','userSession',function($scope,FIREBASE_REF,$firebaseSimpleLogin,userSession){
        $scope.navTitle = 'Entry Page'
        userSession.auth=$firebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase(FIREBASE_REF));
        $scope.login=function(provider){
        userSession.auth.$login(provider)
    }
 }])
```

Comment: Is this code example copy and pasted directly from your app? If so there are a lot of problems, for example you have `$scope : "email,user_like"` If this is not the code copy and pasted exactly can you update it so that it is

Comment: @JacobCarter updated with the code from my app.where i have to set the permissions for getting the email?have any idea?

Comment: What version of $firebase are you using? SimpleLogin has been deprecated. [See Here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebasesimplelogin/).  The first thing I would do is implement the new methods. [See Here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-authentication)

Comment: @JacobCarter firebase version is Firebase v1.0.21.

Comment: I would update to the latest version, you are quite behind in version numbers, since Firebase doesn't technically support what you are doing, you can't expect too much help with it, if you implement the newest version of Firebase (and use the newest methods) it may fix your problem right away, and if it doesnt you will at least have more documentation at your disposal.